# $(TargetDir) replacement for SDK-style projects (analogue to "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\" for "$(ProjectDir)")

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild, csproj

I have an old project in non-SDK-style format generated by Visual Studio. It contains a post-build event in which `$(ProjectDir)` and `$(TargetDir)` are used.

I am currently transforming the project into a new SDK-style project (`csproj` file).
If I just turn that post build event into a `Target` `Exec` `Command`, I get errors. After prefixing the command with `echo` I could see why: The values `$(ProjectDir)` and `$(TargetDir)` were both empty.

I figured out that replacing `$(ProjectDir)` by `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\` gives the desired result, but what is the equivalent for `$(TargetDir)`?

---

Note that I am not using Visual Studio for the new SDK-style project. I am using Visual Studio Code. It seems that Visual Studio sets values for `$(ProjectDir)`/`$(TargetDir)`/others, but Visual Studio Code does not. I build my project using `dotnet build`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems I found the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cafa4b16-c272-4380-ba27-76e6b40e6b4c/how-is-the-targetdir-setting-determined?forum=msbuild):

> The value of TargetDir is computed as the full absolute path of whatever you specify as the Output Path for your project, which is stored in the OutputPath property directly in your project file (.CSPROJ, .VBPROJ, etc.).

So I believe `$(TargetDir)`would be `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutputPath)`.